# Unit test: TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for a class. Here is the test that I've written:

```js
import { GroundAction } from '@lib/shared_types';
import { Ground, Tile } from '../ground';

describe('Ground class', () => {
  let ground: Ground;
  let tiles: Tile[][];

  beforeEach(() => {
    const ground = new Ground(101, 101);
    ground.createGroundAction({ x: 5, z: 5 }, GroundAction.ACTION_1);
    ground.tiles[5][5];
  });

  it('creates a tilled square', () => {
    expect(ground.newTilled).toBe([{ x: 5, z: 5 }]);
  });
}
```

When I run `yarn test` I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

```
> 29 |     const tile = this.tiles[xIndex][zIndex];
     |                  ^
```

Comment: It's probably not the cause of **that** error, but you never assign to the `ground` variable at the top level of your test, because you've shadowed it with a `ground` const that you're assigning to iinstead. You probably want to remove `const` from `const ground = new Ground(101, 101);` inside your `beforeEach` callback.

Comment: We can't help you with this if you don't show us the code containing the line that has the issue, which I'm guessing is in the `Ground` code.

Comment: What are you expecting `ground.tiles[5][5];` to do in your `beforeEach`? That just accesses a property, it doesn't do anything with the resulting value it gets...? (I'm assuming the properties aren't accessors with getter functions that have side-effects, since that would be very poor practice and just seems unlikely.)

Comment: I was trying to initialize the `tiles` property with this statement: `ground.tiles[5][5];`.  
Regarding your other question, `tiles` is just a property on the `Ground` class. This is how I declared it inside the `Ground` class:
`tiles: Tile[][];`

Comment: Right. As I said, the expression `ground.tiles[5][5]` just gets the value from the property, it doesn't *do* anything with it. It doesn't, for instance, initialize the `tiles` variable. (And it wouldn't be the right type if it did, `tiles[5][5]` would be of type `Tile`, wouldn't it? Not `Tile[][]`.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.